# What is "files on IsolatedSorage are preserved" in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows, windows-phone, mobile-application

I came across the term "IsolatedStorage" in windows phone. Can anybody explain it in detail how is it related to windows phone applications?  Also how does it affect while application version upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolated Storage refers the private read / write directories that each app has for storing their own data. It is isolated from all other apps on the system. When an app is upgraded via the store on an end-user's machine, the isolated storage is preserved.

Note that during development, Isolated Storage of an app can be deleted if you do a full rebuild of the project.

Comment: So after app is upgraded via store, end user's phone will preserve the isolated storage for previous version? For different app versions(of same app), different isolated storage are available or same isolated storage will be used?

Comment: It's always the same storage for the same app.

Comment: So there is isolated storage for the app version1.0, and then app is upgraded to version2.0; In this case what kind of data will be stored in isolated storage for version1.0? Also how does it affect to new version2.0?

Comment: The version 2 **code** overwrites the version 1 **code** but the **data** remains in place during upgrade. You can't have both versions of the same app installed at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Code gets overwritten that I wanted to know. Also when we start using the new version, will the data also get overwritten?

Comment: No, any data from version 1 will still be there and can be read by version 2

Answer (score 0):

IsolatedStorage is a way of allowing apps to save files locally to the application within a device. Until the app is uninstalled, the IsolatedStorage for the application is persisted. If the user upgrades the app in the store, as long as there isn't a change in the way the IsolatedStorage is implemented, it will also be preserved during the update.